# How do you configure Files to display the star column?

Tags: files

I use Files (3.36.3-stable) as a file manager in Ubuntu and it has a collection in the sidebar called "Starred." I can star files throughout the other collections and they are automatically listed in the starred collection. This works for all folders and files except those outside home and its path. This means it excludes project related files and code used in development with LAMP, which is in the var path.  Is there anyway to change this behavior so that any file can be starred?  Note that although Files allows you to set preferences for every collection, and that involves selecting to display the Star column, it simply doesn't show.